# Rollback Failed MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
START TRANSACTION;
SAVEPOINT A;
UPDATE employee SET EMP_INITIAL = "P" WHERE EMP_NUM = 102;
COMMIT;
```

When I commit this query it worked, however when I want to do a rollback to the savepoint, it failed. Here is my query for rollback.

```
ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT A;
```

It says that my savepoint A does not exists. Can anyone point out what I am missing?

Comment: Did you COMMIT before you tried to ROLLBACK to A?

Comment: "Did you COMMIT before you tried to ROLLBACK to A?" Joni it's in the manual "All savepoints of the current transaction are **deleted** if you execute a **COMMIT**, or a ROLLBACK that does not name a savepoint. " like @jarlh said see [source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/savepoint.html)

Answer (score 0):

Because you can't `ROLLBACK` after a `COMMIT`. You need to use the `ROLLBACK` clause in a transaction, so before the commit.